# Duvida em Select

Tags: mysql, sql-server, select

Tenho banco de dados mysql com algumas informações cadastradas e preciso buscar através de um select os Campeonato e Modalidades que uma pessoa não tem vinculo, porém já tentei de diversas maneiras e não consegui exito, o máximo que consegui foi buscar as modalidades que não há ninguém cadastrado.

[image: Diagrama]

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente:

```
SELECT modalidades.* FROM modalidades LEFT JOIN inscricoes ON (modalidades.id = inscricoes.id_modalidade)
WHERE inscricoes.id_modalidade IS NULL;
```

Se precisar do nome do campeonato faça:

```
SELECT modalidades.*, campeonato.* 
FROM modalidades INNER JOIN campeonato ON (modalidades.id_campeonato = campeonato.id) 
LEFT JOIN inscricoes ON (modalidades.id = inscricoes.id_modalidade)
WHERE inscricoes.id_modalidade IS NULL;
```

===========

Acrescente ao final da cláusula `ON` de `inscricoes`:

```
AND inscricoes.id_pessoa = id_da_pessoa_desejada
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente as duas maneiras, como eu faria para consultar aquelas modalidades que uma pessoa especifica não está inscrita?

Comment: Não sabia que era possível fazer isso dentro do ON bom saber, dessa maneira resolveu meu problema e me deu novas ideias de uso, muito obrigado!